# How do I divide one kernel density estimate by another?

Tags: r, kernel-density

I am trying to divide one KDE by another KDE to produce a continuous line for which the Y value at any point X is equal to the ratio of the values of the two initial KDEs at that point X.

Below is a reproducible example in the required format. I want to divide `d2` by `d1`, such that a third line is generated with X values from 4 to 8 and Y values ranging from zero (for all X values for which the Y component of `d2` is zero) to approximately 2 (where the Y component of `d2` is approximately twice that of `d1`, as occurs at approx. an X value of 7).

```
set.seed(1)

d1 <- sample(1:10, 30, replace = TRUE)
d2 <- sample(4:8, 30, replace = TRUE)

d1.d <- density(d1, bw = 1)
d2.d <- density(d2, bw = 1)

plot(d1.d, 
     main = "KDE of d1 (black) and d2 (blue)",
     ylim = c(0,0.25))
lines(d2.d, col = "blue")
```

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I think `plot(d1.d$x, d1.d$y/d2.d$y, type = "l")` will produce the line you're after, but I can't figure out how to plot it with the `density` objects on the same plot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Defining `from=` and `to=` in both `density`es from their joint `range` enables to do arithmetic operations in the *y* values.

```
> rg <- range(c(d1, d2))
> 
> d1.d <- density(d1, bw = 1, from=rg[1], to=rg[2], n=512)
> d2.d <- density(d2, bw = 1, from=rg[1], to=rg[2], n=512)
> 
> ratio <- d2.d$y/d1.d$y
> 
> par(mar=c(5, 4, 4, 3))
> plot(d1.d, main = "KDE of d1 (black) and d2 (blue)", 
+      ylim=range(c(d1.d$y, d2.d$y)))
> lines(d2.d, col=4)
> fac <- 1/20
> lines(d1.d$x, ratio*fac, type='l', col=2, lty=2)
> axis(4, axTicks(2), labels=axTicks(2)/fac, col=2, col.axis=2)
> mtext('ratio', 4, 2, col=2)
> legend('topleft', legend=c('d1', 'd2', 'ratio'), col=c(1, 4, 2), lty=c(1, 1, 2))
```

### [image]

*Data:*

```
> dput(d1)
c(9L, 4L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 6L, 10L, 7L, 
9L, 5L, 5L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 10L)
> dput(d2)
c(5L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 
5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L)
```

Comment: @jay.sf, the ratio term is still backwards as of now. How did you arrive at a value of 1/20 for 'fac.' It seems to work, but I can't figure out how you knew to use that value specifically.

Comment: @overcup I used `ratio*fac` as well as  `axTicks(2)/fac` which should make it consistent. `1/20` just looked nice :)

Comment: @jay.sf, ah so `fac` is largely/entirely aesthetic? I assumed you used a value of `fac` that would scale the ratio line so that the area underneath would be equal to 1.

Comment: To get a proper PDF you also have to divide by the integral. Not sure if this is what OP is going for or not though. Still, one could do `integrate(approxfun(...), ...)` of the density over the defined area and then divide the density with that number.

Comment: @jay.sf, I'm sorry, I completely missed that you included a separate ratio scale on the right side of the plot. Your use of the 1/20 scale makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

You can turn the result of `density()` into a function using `approxfun()`.  You only need to do this for one of the density estimates; you can use the `x` and `y` values from the other one directly:

```r
set.seed(1)

d1 <- sample(1:10, 30, replace = TRUE)
d2 <- sample(4:8, 30, replace = TRUE)

d1.d <- density(d1, bw = 1)
d2.d <- density(d2, bw = 1)
d2.f <- approxfun(d2.d$x, d2.d$y)

plot(d1.d, 
     main = "KDE of d1 (black) and d2 (blue)",
     ylim = c(0,3))
lines(d2.d, col = "blue")
lines(d1.d$x, d2.f(d1.d$x)/d1.d$y, col = "red")
legend("topleft", legend = c("d1", "d2", "d2/d1"), 
       col = c("black", "blue", "red"), lty=1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-11-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>